# python Thread not stop as expectation

Tags: python, multithreading

This program is to capture video from a webcam and display it in a tkinter window using Threading to process video data. It's expected that all threads stop when the tkinter frame is closed by clicking the close button of the tkinter window. The problem is that only thread CaptureVideo can stop normally, thread ShowVideo cannot. How to make the two threads stop after clicking the close button of the tkinter window?

version: Python 3.10.4, Pillow 9.5.0, Windows 11 22H2

The whole program is not long and to avoid missing anything buggy and faciliate you to debug, all codes are pasted as follows.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import queue
import threading
import time
import cv2


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def createWidgets(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master=self, width=640, height=480)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    def set_canvas(self, image):
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image, anchor='nw')

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(fill=tk.X)
        self.createWidgets()


class CaptureVideo (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        print("Start thread:" + self.name)
        self.capture_data()
        # This thread can exit!
        print("Exit thread:" + self.name)

    def capture_data(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        while cap.isOpened():
            global THREAD_EXIT_SIGNAL
            if THREAD_EXIT_SIGNAL:
                cap.release()
                break
            _, frame = cap.read()
            queue_video_data_lock.acquire()
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            queue_video_data.put(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA))
            queue_video_data_lock.release()


class ShowVideo (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        print("Start thread:" + self.name)
        self.use_data()
        # This thread cannot exit!!!
        print("Exit thread:" + self.name)

    def use_data(self):
        while not THREAD_EXIT_SIGNAL:
            queue_video_data_lock.acquire()
            if not queue_video_data.empty():
                data = queue_video_data.get()
                queue_video_data_lock.release()

                image = Image.fromarray(data)
                # The program stuck at below step. If removing it, thread can exit.
                photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=image)
                form.set_canvas(photo)
                var1 = None
                var1 = photo
            else:
                queue_video_data_lock.release()


def change_thread_exit_signal():
    global THREAD_EXIT_SIGNAL
    THREAD_EXIT_SIGNAL = 1
    tk_root.destroy()


tk_root = tk.Tk()
tk_root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", change_thread_exit_signal)


form = Application(master=tk_root)

threads = []
THREAD_EXIT_SIGNAL = 0
queue_video_data_lock = threading.Lock()
queue_video_data = queue.Queue(1000)

thread_capture_video = CaptureVideo(1, 'thread_capture_video')
thread_capture_video.start()
threads.append(thread_capture_video)

thread_show_video = ShowVideo(2, 'thread_show_video')
thread_show_video.start()
threads.append(thread_show_video)

form.mainloop()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

The problem can be traced from the output as follows.  Only thread_capture_video stops. thread_show_video doesn't stop.

```
> py .\main.py
Start thread:thread_capture_video
Start thread:thread_show_video
Exit thread:thread_capture_video
```

I have tried to remove some lines to find which one prevents the thread from stopping. It seems that "ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=image)" in "ShowVideo" class is the one preventing thread_show_video thread from stopping. If removing it, the thread can stop. However, it should not be removed as it is the core function.

Comment: Probably the `PhotoImage` requires a running main loop. At the end of both `run` functions you can add a `tk_root.after` which calls a function to inform that the respective thread ended. The function records that (e. g. by deleting the thread from `threads`) and when all threads ended, it terminates the main loop.

Comment: Missing is `cv2.waitKey(0)`.

Comment: @Michael I am not sure how to implement what you guide. Could you please provide more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the `PhotoImage` requires a running main loop. At the end of both `run` functions you can add a `tk_root.after_idle` which calls a function to inform that the respective thread ended. The function records that (e. g. by deleting the thread from threads) and when all threads ended, it terminates the main loop.

Practically this is done by changing the `run` methods to:

```
class CaptureVideo (threading.Thread):
    ...
    def run(self):
        print("Start thread:" + self.name)
        self.capture_data()
        # This thread can exit!
        print("Exit thread:" + self.name)
        tk_root.after_idle(thread_end_check, self)


class ShowVideo (threading.Thread):
    ...
    def run(self):
        print("Start thread:" + self.name)
        self.use_data()
        # This thread cannot exit!!!
        print("Exit thread:" + self.name)
        tk_root.after_idle(thread_end_check, self)
```

Removing last line from `change_thread_exit_signal`:

```
def change_thread_exit_signal():
    global THREAD_EXIT_SIGNAL
    THREAD_EXIT_SIGNAL = 1
```

And defining function:

```
def thread_end_check(t):
    global threads

    threads.remove(t)
    if len(threads) == 0:
        tk_root.destroy()
```

Comment: Awecome! It works! Thanks a million! One more question, `ShowVideo` cannot stop therefore `print("Exit thread:" + self.name)` cannot be reached,  why `tk_root.after_idle(thread_end_check, self)` can be reached which is after  `print("Exit thread:" + self.name)` ?

Comment: Your original code calls `tk_root.destroy()` (which stops the main loop) while threads are running yet. Something in the `ShowVideo` thread, probably the `PhotoImage` constructor, needs a running main loop and waits. My code calls `tk_root.destroy()` after the threads terminated or immediately before termination.